# Java: tools.jar not accessible for javaagent

Tags: java, javaagents

I am developping a Java agent which is using some classes from `tools.jar` via reflection like `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Options`.

For testing my agent I am setting `set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:path-to-my-agent-jar` and launching a build on a simple gradle project to which the java agent will be hooked.

I have added `tools.jar` to the classpath of the gradle project and checked that is correctly added to the classpath.

My agent is correctly hooked to the build process.

My problem seems to be that the agent has no access to the classloader(s) used for building so he could not find classes from tools.jar and raises

```
java.lang.Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/tools/javac/util/Options
```

Is there anyway I can add tools.jar to my java agent ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: _tools.jar_ is part of the JDK libraries . Is your application launched with a JDK ?

Comment: Yes, In fact I am hooking my agent to gradle  : my agent is hooking on methods of classes from tools.jar used for compiling java source code .

Answer (score 0):

Import jdk to your build path in project properties.In eclipse, Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries
(i.e) ....\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib tools.jar will be present here

Comment: I don't want to have a direct dependency to tools.jar for practical reasons . my aim is to add it to the client application on which my agent will be hooked .

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution.

We have two java applications: the gradle which will be building a gradle project and the javaagent that is hooked to the first java application. Both of them are living in the same JVM but each of them is using it's classloader.

Because of that the classes of `tools.jar` are accessible in the gradle project and not in the java agent.

The idea is to use the classloader of the gradle application from the agent.

For this we we have to access of one of the object created inside the gradle project from within the java agent. Actually, I am accessing it via bytecode enhancement.

if `objectFromFirstApp` is from the gradle application I can access to `tools.jar` via `objectFromFirstApp.getClass().getClassLoader().load("ClassName")`.